# Get first part of string in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, implode

I've got a string of:

```
test1.doc,application/msword,/tmp/phpDcvNQ5,0,23552
```

I want the first part before the comma. How do I get the first part 'test1.doc' on it's own without the rest of the string?

The string came from an array I imploded:

```
$uploadFlag=implode( ',', $uploadFlag );
echo $uploadFlag;
```

If it's easier to extract just the first value off the array on it's own that would also do the job. I don't think the array has any keys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) in combo with [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$parts = explode(',', $uploadFlag);
$firstPart = $parts[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

`echo $uploadFlag[0];`

Uh, try that in place of that whole chunk of code. Since you're imploding it, you could just grab the first piece instead. That ought to echo the proper value!

Comment: @JamWaffles: I was wondering that myself. Saves some processing time, OP could just implode after if they need it imploded!

Comment: This only works if the value is indeed at index `0`. Better use `reset()` and `current()` if that's not a certainty.

Comment: If the OP still has to `implode()`, the above answer would need to happen *before* the `implode()` overwrote `$uploadFlag`.

Comment: @Radu: That makes no sense, we're not iterating through the loop. The zeroth index is the zeroth index is the zeroth index...

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Indeed, hence "OP could just implode after"

Comment: I would think that should be part of the answer content, not in a comment below it. `;)`

Comment: @Cyclone, the first index in the array (which is actually a hash table, not an array, as implemented by PHP) could very well be `100` or `bob`, thus `$uploadFlag[0]` might not reference anything.

Comment: If the original array is associative $uploadFlag[0] wouldn't necessarily exist would it? `echo array_shift( $uploadFlag );` would be the zeroth element in both an associative and numbered array

Comment: @Ben Swinburne, `array_shift()` though would alter the array, which is not intended.

Comment: @Radu, indeed it would. Perhaps `echo array_shift(array_slice($array, 0, 1));` would be more suited. Leaves the original array in tact.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
$part = substr($uploadFlag , 0, strpos($uploadFlag , ','));
```

Answer (score 2):

To extract it from the string, you can use [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace) for example.

```
$firstPart = preg_replace('/,.*$/', '', $uploadFlag);
```

In the above example, the regular expression replaces everything (`.*`) that follows the first comma (`,`) until the end of the string (`$`) with nothing (`''`).

Or, if you can use the `$uploadFlag` array before replacing it with the imploded string, then you can use [`reset()`](http://www.php.net/reset) to go to the first element in the array and [`current()`](http://www.php.net/current) to extract its value.

```
reset($uploadFlag);
$firstPart = current($uploadFlag);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Implode` is not the right function. It takes an array and combines into one string. You are trying to do the reverse operation, which is handled by `explode`:

```
    $uploadFlag=explode( ',', $uploadFlag );
    echo $uploadFlag;
```

Comment: He said that `$uploadFlag` came from an array he imploded, meaning that it currently is in string format. And he mentioned that the entire string was what was returned by implode. That means, he needs to explode $uploadFlag.

Comment: If the OP has it in an array format already, then get the first value before imploding. See @Cyclone's answer.

Answer (score 0):

`echo array_shift(array_slice($uploadFlag, 0, 1));` will output the first element of your array beit an associative or numbered array.

Comment: Tidied up answer to prevent it changing the original array structure